# Вывод имен файлов в массив

Tags: php

Массив в котором будем хранить допустимые имена файлов и их русские названия

```
<?php
$pages=array(
'123'=>'О нас'
);
?>
```

Вопрос: какой код нужно вставить код что бы в массив подставлялись автоматом имена созданных файлов на сервере ??? (123-это имя файла без его расширения)

Comment: Если честно, то я не понял суть вопроса..

Comment: Таким образом выводятся ссылки на существующие страницы, но после создания страницы приходится вписывать в ручную (123-имя файла, О нас- выводимое имя файла, как ссылка) нужно что бы после создания страницы скрипт сам считывал имеющиеся файлы и выводил их имена в массив.

Comment: А как будут вводиться названия ссылок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$directory = '/';
$all_files = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));

$array_of_files = array();
foreach($all_files as $file){
  $content = file_get_contents(trim($directory,'/').'/'.$file);
  $match = preg_match('/<title>(.*)</title>/i',$content,$match);
  $match = $match[1];
    $array_of_files[$file] = $match;  
}
```

//Писалось на коленке. Принцип такой, ошибки, думаю, поправите.